# SIGSEGV and SIGABRT with no apparent reason in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, pointers, sigabrt, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to read a full message from a socket which can be very long with this code:

```
int readWholeMessage(char* &message){
    bool ended=false;
    bool first=true;
    int mlen=0;
    int len = BUFFLEN;
    char* buffer;
    char* sol=new char[BUFFLEN];
    while(!ended) {
        buffer = new char[BUFFLEN];
        n = (int) read(s, buffer, (size_t) BUFFLEN);
        if (n < 0) {
            perror("ERROR reading from socket");
            close(s);
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            //looks for the end of the message: "\r\n"          
            for(int i=0; i<BUFFLEN-1; i++){
                mlen++;
                if(buffer[i]=='\r' && buffer[i+1]=='\n'){
                    ended=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            mlen++;
            //saves the result in sol and deletes buffer
            if(first){
                strcpy(sol, buffer);
                first=false;
            }
            //creates a new bigger array, saves the whole message,
            //deletes de old array points the pointer sol to the new one
            else {
                len+=BUFFLEN;
                char *bufferAux = new char[len+1];
                strcpy(bufferAux, sol);
                strcat(bufferAux,buffer);
                delete [] sol;
                sol=bufferAux;
            }
            delete [] buffer;
        }
    }
    message = new char[mlen+1];
    strncpy(message, sol, (size_t) mlen);
    message[mlen]= '\0';
    delete[](sol);
    return 0;
}
```

but SIGSEGV and SIGABRT appear randomly in delete[] sol; and delete[] buffer; depending on the length of the message to read.
Adding 1 solves the problem if BUFFSIZE is 8 but I need it to be 256. 
Some help please?

Comment: on one branch you delete the buffer on the other you dont. I would rather fix that problem as a whole (RAII) and hope that the SIGs were caused by that

Comment: `strcpy(sol, buffer);` is wrong. The buffer isn't null-terminated.

Comment: You have `delete[] sol` in two places -- inside the `for` loop and also after the loop is done.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<BUFFLEN-1; i++)` should use `i < n-1`, not `i < BUFFLEN-1`.

Comment: And that won't work if `\r` is the last character of this buffer and `\n` is the first character of the next buffer.

Comment: What's the point of the `ended` variable? You only use it in `while(!ended)`, but you also have `break` immediately after setting it to `true`. You could just use `while (true)`.

Comment: @tobi303, actually delete [] buffer is outside the if-else set so it's always deleted isn't it?

Comment: @GabrielModiaPozuelo `if (n < 0)` the buffer is not deleted

Comment: @GabrielModiaPozuelo It's in the `else` block of the first `if`.

Comment: A lot of this code could be reduced and made safer by simply using `std::vector<char>` for your buffer and not having to issue any calls to `delete[]` or do manual memory management to resize things..  Probably would run faster to, since you wouldn't be calling the allocator on every single iteration of the loop.

Comment: All your uses of `strcpy` and `strcat` are wrong, since `read()` doesn't create a null-terminated string.

Comment: @Barmar, making all them null-terminated fixed it, thanks you so much to everyone!

Comment: Might as well migrate this entire question and comment thread to a chatroom, since nobody here has correctly treated this website as a Q&A repository.

Comment: The logic is really hard to follow. If you use new/delete and stick to C++, why not using containers and letting handle the resize etc. for you automatically? They were created for that reason. You will be able to remove a lot of lines of code. If you need contiguous memory use vector, otherwise consider using deque which will allocate memory in pages for you.